# Django queries and specific sorting

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-models, django-queryset

I am quite new to Django and it's way of doing queries. I think I got the basics now but I'm stuck at a sorting problem.

So let's say I have this example model:

```
class Word_List(models.Model):
  list_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
  number_of_words = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I have a few data :

```
pk      list_name      number_of_words

1       vegetables     30
2       fruits         5
3       animals        7
4       objects        15
5       instruments    16
6       fruits         28
```

Now I want them to be sorted by the number_of_words and then grouped by list_name with the top list being the important one in the grouping. Here, a clearer explanation with the sorted elements I have in mind :

```
pk      list_name      number_of_words

1       vegetables     30
6       fruits         28
2       fruits         5
5       instruments    16
4       objects        15
3       animals        7
```

I have tried a few things but I never fully reached what I wanted. I started with this :

```
sorted_lists = Word_List.objects.all().order_by('-number_of_words')
```

Of course it wasn't enough as it only sort every element regardless of their names so I tried this one :

```
sorted_lists = Word_List.objects.all().order_by('list_name', -'number_of_words')
```

And ended up with this result :

```
pk      list_name      number_of_words

3       animals        7    
6       fruits         28
2       fruits         5
5       instruments    16
4       objects        15
1       vegetables     30
```

Aaaand I'm stuck, I'm thinking of doing post-request sorting using basic python and multi-loops or maybe somehow with multiple requests and then joining the results but I feel like there might be a clean and beautiful solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way of achieving this is:

```
query = Word_List.objects.all().query
query.group_by = ['-list_name']
query.order_by = ['-number_of_words']
sorted_list = QuerySet(query=query, model=Word_List)
```

Note that this may be changed in future version of Django as it is not documented. Use Raw SQL queries to be safe:

```
Word_List.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM appname_Word_List ORDER_BY ....')
```